# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

Tags: php, sql

I've got problem about my HTML5 application.

If I submit the form, I got this message:

```
 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Left, Width, Height, Opacity) VALUES ('DADobjImg1-1',1,87,8,200,184,100)' at line 1
```

and this is my code...

```
if($DADimg != "0" || $DADimg != "undefined"){
for($i = 1; $i <= $DADimgs; $i++){
if($_POST["DADobjPropI".$i] != "" || $_POST["DADobjPropI".$i] != "undefined"){
$DADgenNameI = $_POST["DADobjPropF".$i]."-".$DADtableRow;
$DADimg1 = $_POST["DADobjPropI".$i];
$DADimg2 = $_POST["DADobjPropY".$i];
$DADimg3 = $_POST["DADobjPropX".$i];
$DADimg4 = $_POST["DADobjPropW".$i];
$DADimg5 = $_POST["DADobjPropH".$i];
$DADimg6 = $_POST["DADobjPropO".$i];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (ID, Image, Top, Left, Width, Height, Opacity) VALUES ('$DADgenNameI',$DADimg1,$DADimg2,$DADimg3,$DADimg4,$DADimg5,$DADimg6)") or die (mysql_error());
if($i <= $DADimgs && $i==1){$DADsepStartI="['";}else{$DADsepStartI="'";}
 if($i == $DADimgs){$DADsepEndI="']";}else{$DADsepEndI="',";}
 $DADimages=$DADimages.$DADsepStartI.$DADgenNameI.$DADsepEndI;
 echo $DADgenNameI." ".$DADimg1." ".$DADimg2." ".$DADimg3." ".$DADimg4." ".$DADimg5." ".$DADimg6."<br/>";
 }
 }
 }
```

I try to use mysql_real_escape_string() but this problem still appear...

anyone can help me?

Comment: Ungh.... the question title doesn't say much, really

Comment: @DaveChen actually, `mysql_` has already been deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Left` is a keywords. Use bakticks

```
`Left`
```

Consider stopping using `mysql_` functions. They are deprecated. Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead

Comment: wow, thanks ^^ my problem is fixed. I'm newbie on PHP programming. :) thank you so much :)